# How to remove class when page loads but only once

Tags: html, jquery

I have a button that toggles `active` class on a div.

When the div has `active` class it is displayed and when `active` class is removed the div is hidden.

I want `active` class removed from the div when the page is loaded, but later when I click the button `active` class should be applied.  The div should be hidden when the page loads.

I don't have access to HTML so it has to be done using jquery.

here is my code:

```
<button class="btn addclass">Toggle class</button>
<div class="block active">
</div>
```

my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('load', function(){
    if($(".addclass .block").hasClass("active")){
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".addclass").click(function(){
    $(".block").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.block{
  display: none;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.block.active{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your if statement is not complete, it's missing a `)`

Comment: Yes, i forgot to add it but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this block of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('load', function(){
    if ($(".addclass .block").hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
  });
```

`this` refers to the `window` so you can't use `window` here.

You also don't shouldn't nest window.load inside doc.ready (use one or the other).  While doc.ready will fire even if the document is already ready, window load will only fire at the one time that it loads and that will be before doc.ready runs, so your code (probably) never runs.

Your code can be shortened to:

```
$(function() { 
    $(".addclass .block.active").removeClass("active"); 
});
```

Comment: I just found out that the active class was taking some time to apply, so I added timeout on your code and it worked. Thank you

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.   Do you know how/when the active class is applied?  It might be  possible to "hook into" that process, eg via an event or a callback or ajax events.  `setTimeout` can be risky as there might be a longer delay than you're expecting on occasion.

Comment: After the page loads it takes 2 3 seconds.
I was working on Magento2 and i don't have much knowledge about this framework.
It's some kind of gift message to send, if you want to gift any product to someone

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery specializes in controlling all things DOM it's a shade faster and less flashing if you listen for the `"DOMContentLoaded"` event on the `document` object. By that time all of the DOM is loaded and the scripts have been parsed. If you listen to the `"load"` event on the `window` object, then everything has been loaded, that includes all the stuff you didn't need to run jQuery.

BTW if you don't already know, it's important that all `<script>` elements be placed right before the closing `</body>` tag. Of course this may not be possible for you since you have to deal with 3rd party code at page load. See this [article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/running_your_code_at_the_right_time.htm) about what was just discussed.

```js
/*
Once document is loaded
Remove .active from .block
*/
$(document).on('DOMContentLoaded', e => $('.block').removeClass('active'));

/* ALTERNATIVE
Once document is loaded
Hide .block
/
$(document).on('DOMContentLoaded', e => $('.block').hide());
*/

/*
When .toggle is clicked...
Toggle .block to hide/show
Toggle the text of .toggle to "SHOW/HIDE"
*/
$('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).text($(this).text() === 'SHOW' ? 'HIDE' : 'SHOW');

  /*
  Toggle .active class on/off on .block
  */
  $('.block').toggleClass('active');

  /* ALTERNATIVE
  Toggle .block show/hide slowly
  /
  $('.block').toggle('slow');
  */
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 5ch/1 Consolas;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn toggle">SHOW</button>
<div class="block active">ACTIVE</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```